# Floating point issue in C when solving a math expression

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a problem solving math function in C.

```
double task1_double() {
    double a = 1000;
    double b = 0.0001;
    double result = (pow((a + b), 2) - (pow(a, 2) + 2 * a * b))/(pow(b, 2));
    return result; }

float task1_float() {
    float a = 1000;
    float b = 0.0001f;
    float result = (powf((a + b), 2) - (powf(a, 2) + 2 * a * b))/(powf(b, 2));
    return result; }
```

When I use a double data type it returns 1.001172, though with float data type the result is 6250000.000000.

Can somebody explain why this happens? Thanks in advance

Comment: Split up the compound expressions into simpler ones, using temporary doubles to hold the intermediate results.  Print out everything and so narrow down where the error is generated.  This is called 'debugging'.  You could also use an actual debugger to trace through the execution line-by-line, inspecting values at each stage.

Comment: i found a problem, float b = 0.0001 saves 9.99999975e-05 in spite of saving 0.0001. Can i fix it someway?

Comment: Use double for everything.  That will mitigate, but not eliminate, the inherent issue with any floating point representation that tries, (and fails), to cover an infinite range of values with non-infinite RAM.

Comment: Just in case this is an actual problem: The formula simplifies to 1, mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numerator is exactly

```
1000000.20000001 - 1000000.2 = 0.00000001
```

but when you subtract two large numbers which are almost equal, the relative rounding error in the result can blow up. This is what you are seeing. It is a consequence of the fact that `float` numbers have about 7 decimal digits of precision, whereas `double` numbers have about 16 decimal digits.

Let's do it step by step:

```
                           exact            float        double
x = pow((a + b), 2)        1000000.20000001 1000000.25   1000000.200000009965
y = pow(a, 2) + 2 * a * b  1000000.2        1000000.1875 1000000.199999999953
x - y                      0.00000001       0.0625       0.000000010011717677
```

For such a small difference between the two numbers relative to their magnitude, you would usually get a `float` result equal to 0.0. But in this case it just happens that 1000000.20000001 and 1000000.2 lie either side of a rounding boundary, causing the former to be rounded up and the latter to be rounded down. So their difference is out by six orders of magnitude.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much
your explanation's perfect

Answer (score 1):

By outputting intermediate results, it can be found that it is caused by the loss of precision of float

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double task1_double() {
    double a = 1000;
    double b = 0.0001;
    double s1, s2, s3;
    s1 = pow((a + b), 2);
    s2 = pow(a, 2) + 2 * a * b;
    s3 = pow(b, 2);
    double result = (pow((a + b), 2) - (pow(a, 2) + 2 * a * b)) / (pow(b, 2));

    printf("_double : %lf - %lf = %.15lf\n", s1, s2, s1 - s2);
    printf("_double : (%lf - %lf) / %.10lf = %lf\n", s1, s2, s3, result);

    return result;
}

float task1_float() {
    float a = 1000;
    float b = 0.0001f;
    float s1, s2, s3;
    s1 = powf((a + b), 2);
    s2 = powf(a, 2) + 2 * a * b;
    s3 = powf(b, 2);
    float result = (powf((a + b), 2) - (powf(a, 2) + 2 * a * b)) / (powf(b, 2));

    printf("_float : %lf - %lf = %.15lf\n", s1, s2, s1 - s2);
    printf("_float : (%lf - %lf) / %.10lf = %lf\n", s1, s2, s3, result);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%.10lf\n%.10lf\n", task1_double(), task1_float());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
_float : 1000000.250000 - 1000000.187500 = 0.062500000000000
_float : (1000000.250000 - 1000000.187500) / 0.0000000100 = 6250000.500000
_double : 1000000.200000 - 1000000.200000 = 0.000000010011718
_double : (1000000.200000 - 1000000.200000) / 0.0000000100 = 1.001172
1.0011717677
6250000.5000000000
```

As can be seen:
After the float is operated, a slight error occurs, but dividing by the small value of b will cause the error to be magnified many times

Comment: No, it's not the division that causes the problem, it's the subtraction. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK: The subtraction has a result with increased relative error. The division has a result with increased absolute error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: but it is the subtraction that _causes the problem_, isn't it? The division is well-behaved, with no rounding issues. It does nothing to explain the OP's surprising result.

Comment: @TonyK: I would not say so. Subtraction of two numbers close in value never adds any error. That the relative error in its output is greater than the relative error in its inputs is not its fault. The actual origin of the error is earlier, in the rounding of the source text `0.0001f` to `float` and the `+` and `pow` operations. Why should `-` get the blame when it did its job perfectly with no error and everybody else screwed up?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I am at a loss for words (and that doesn't happen often). Have you read my answer? Do you disagree with it?

Comment: @TonyK: I saw your answer and I am well familiar with the behavior of error in subtraction (notably Sterbenz’ lemma) and other operations. The effect that subtraction of two close numbers produces a result with greater relative error than in the inputs may be of some use for understanding or analyzing the error in some situations, but it is not the **cause** of the problem, as you asked about above.

Comment: @TonyK I admit that if there is no error in the subtraction, the final result will not be wrong, but the multiplication does magnify the error. (Just like "After the float is operated, a slight error occurs" in my original text)

Comment: ipnah, it is always the _relative_ error that is important. This is unchanged by that harmless division.

Comment: You are right
By the way, "multiplication" in my comment actually refers to "division" because of a typo